# How to make flour model?

Tags: modeling

I am working on a project and I should create a 3D model that looks like a **pile of flour**, how can I make it? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create this kind of topology:

[image]

Then mix a texture of flour (that you've painted with a stencil brush) and a texture of wood table, use a b&w mask as factor, also plug the flour texture into a *Bump* to get a bit more 3d effect:

[image]

This would give something like that:

[image]

Comment: I would say this is a pretty good start, but OP should definitely remember to get some of the smaller "ball-like" clumpy shapes, in there. I think if they rely on the erosion effect to get the noise "mound" shape it gives too strong of mountain vibes IMO. They could either use an additional displace modifier on the model, or some kind of particle system, maybe a combo of both.

Comment: sure it's far from perfect, the hardest thing to achieve is the crumbling effect, if he tries to simulate that

Comment: actually it may be better to think about it as a ground with stones (with particles as you say)