# Node configuration for salt texture which can look bit realistic

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am trying to get a salt like texture in Blender 3.2 and EEVEE, I have tried many things like noise textures, image textures and Geometry Nodes but none of that can make a realistic approach.

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

[image: This is I have made on my own]

[image: This is the node configuration]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44606/how-to-make-an-object-appear-to-be-buried-in-sand https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261077/how-to-make-flour-model

Answer (score 3):

You can start with Voronoi texture:

[image]

Combine channels to make a normal map, like each individual Voronoi patch is rotated in different angle:

[image]

Add some noise and search for right specular and roughless settings:

[image]

You can also use unused channel from Voronoi like this:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou , it really worked , was stuck in this issue for about a week .